# Why is 11 an important number in I-Origins

Tags: plot-explanation, i-origins

I'm talking about the movie [I-Origins](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2884206)

Wonderful movie. Movie about science vs religion. Fact vs believe. Cool. Scientist IAN lost the girl after first interaction but he can't forget about her. He never saw her face but fell for her because of her amazing eyes. Then one day the number '11' started appearing before him a countless number of times. He started to focus on it and then he found her eyes in an advertisement board. Okay! But why eleven?

How is eleven relevant with this? The movie also started with showing the binary number `1011` which is in decimal `11`

What is the significance of eleven in this movie? Did the director/writer mention anything about why eleven is used? And how is eleven relevant with the context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The movie deals with, on a certain level, chance vs fate.  If you believe in fate, you believe there is a particular order of events that is pre-destined.  You also likely believe in patterns that define those events.  Numerologists have a fascination with 11, and specifically [11:11 and events linked to it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/11:11_(numerology)), which appear to happen at a frequency which surpasses chance.

Answer (score 2):

11s or 11:11 have a strong chance leading you to your soulmate or twinflame. When Sofi said they are connected from past lives is because they truly are twin flames probably. And that's why the 11 shows up constantly to lead him to her. Its called synchronicity. Coincidence is an illusion in the spiritual world.

Comment: This is interesting, having 11s lead you to a soulmate, but can you add any links here with backup for this?  I'd be interested to read about it.

Answer (score 0):

We also see the number '11' at the end when Ian find Salomina. He found her in 11 days (he spent 20.000$ with a 2.000$ daily cost since the second day he arrived in India). 
Salomina had 44% of good answer in the final test. It means she gave 11 good answers out of 25 questions. Otherwise, it's 11% over the mid note which would be 33% (1 chance out of 3).
This movie is amasing!